# How can i override DELETE method in django?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models Document and User with some fields:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    '''
    some fields
    '''
    access = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None)
```

and

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    '''
    some fields
    '''
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_deleted = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
```

I want to delete some document using DELETE method, but i get error

```
ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model, are m2m fields, or are non-concrete fields: is_active, date_deleted
```

So, how can i override DELETE method or use some other approach to remove document?

Comment: How are you trying to delete it? From a view, serializer, etc, could you provide the respective code snippet?